# Find sample size required for hypothesis to hold true

Tags: statistics

A coach has made a statement that his players have bigger lung capacity than the average of the population of the same age which is $3.4$. (Normal distribution)

The measurements yield the following data: 3.4, 3.6, 3.8, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.7, 3.6, 3.7, 3.4 and 3.6.

$n=11$

$\bar{X}=3.545$

$S=0.157$

Find the required sample size, which lung capacity should be measured, so coach can state his statement with 99% confidence. (assume $\sigma^2=0.09$)

I don't even know how should I start. My initial thought was to use the $U$ statistics $U=\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}$~$N(0,1)$. But I don't know the $U$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup is 
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
H_0 &:& \mbox{average lung capacity of players equals population average} \newline
H_1 &:& \mbox{average lung capacity of players > population average} 
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

So, since we can define $Z{}\sim{}N(0,1)$ where $Z{}:={}\dfrac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$, in order to reject $H_0$ we need a sample-size $n$ such that
$$
P\left(Z{}>{}Z_{0.01}\right){}={}0.01\,.
$$

$Z_{0.01}{}\approx{}2.33$ can be determined from Standard-Normal tables. Thus, for $\bar{X}{}={}3.545$, $\mu{}={}3.4$  and $\sigma^2{}={}0.09$, $n$ should be, at least,

$$
n{}={}\left(\dfrac{Z_{0.01}0.3}{3.545-3.4}\right)^2{}\approx{}23.24\,,
$$

about twice the number of players the coach has at present! But, of course, if the sample variance is used (and, why not, since this should be indicative of how similar the team members are) instead of the population variance, we have, instead,

$$
n{}\approx{}6.36
$$

which is half of the team-size; the coach has more than enough "evidence" in this regard. This is not surprising: the coach was selective in choosing his players, in that they display top physical ability and, therefore, might be more likely to have "larger" lungs, on average, than that of the population.

**Edit**: This is in response to questions asked by @OwlCity.
The coach suspects that the average lung size for a team he selects is greater than the population average. When he selects a team, the average lung size of the team can vary, depending on who he has selected to be in the team. This is $\bar{X}$: it is a random variable with some probability distribution. If the average of $\bar{X}$ is $\mu$ with variance $\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}$ then, for large enough $n$, the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) allows us to approximate the distribution of $\dfrac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$ by a standard normal random variable $Z$ with mean $0$ and variance $1$. This is a technical way of saying that for large samples, any of the probability statements you can make with $\bar{X}$ you can make in some equivalent form using the distribution of $Z$. This means that the coach, wanting to gain some confidence in his suspicions characterised by $H_1$, can do the following:

1) He can assume that he is wrong, so he assumes $H_0$ instead of $H_1$, and then he checks to see whether (with this assumption of $H_0$) the data shows evidence to cast doubt on $H_0$;

2) In order to perform this check, he chooses a very small probability, $0.01$ in fact, of him selecting a team with $\bar{X}$ being far away from the population average;

3) Using the distribution of $Z$ (because the Central limit theorem says we can "replace" the distribution of $\dfrac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$ with that of $Z$), the coach can proceed as follows:
$$
P\left(\dfrac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}{}>{}\dfrac{3.545-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}\right){}={}P\left(Z{}>{}Z_{0.01}\right){}={}0.01\,.
$$

That is, the coach can ask, "what is the number $Z_{0.01}{}={}\dfrac{3.545-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$, such that the probability of selecting a team with $\bar{X}{}>{}3.545$ is $0.01$"? This number, $Z_{0.01}$, can be read from Standard-Normal tables to be $2.33$.

Comment: May I ask how do we get the $P(Z>Z_{0.01} ) = 0.01$? What does it mean? And why $Z_{0.01}$?